# Path to redirect to the same page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

If "root_path" takes you to the root page, what's the equivalent path to redirect you to the same page?

Here's the context: I'm using Devise for logging in users on a Rails 4.0 app, and my "custom_failure.rb" file currently redirects the user to the root page if login is unsuccessful.

Right now, a failed login will take the user to the root path.  But the login form is on every page on the site, and if someone makes a failed login on page X, I want that user to stay on page X (or at least be redirected back to it).

Here's my "custom_failure.rb" file right now:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    root_path
  end
.
.
end
```

What should I type in to replace "root_path"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use    `request.referrer` to redirect to the same page

Comment: That's not working.  When I do a failed login, the browser takes me to the route "/unauthenticated", and I get this message: 'No route matches [GET] "/unauthenticated".'

Comment: It's spelled "referrer," not "referer," but it did the trick!  Thank you!

Comment: oops sorry.typo.please accept the answer if it solved the issue

Comment: BTW, my very first comment might be confusing, so let me clarify: the original answer that user123 suggested was "request.path".  THAT was the suggestion that didn't work.  "request.referrer", on the other hand, does indeed work.  Stack Overflow won't let me edit my first comment, though.  :-P

Comment: Both versions are accepted apparently `referrer` or `referer`. Because the HTTP request Header is written this way:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Etymology

Answer (score 2):

you can use `redirect_to :back` 
Method. After executing the controller, it will reload the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `redirect_back_or_to signin_path` ? It might help.